# How to create new table from a distinct table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

i currently have a table named my_table, like:

[image]

now when i run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country,Zipcode,Plan_Id FROM my_table;
```

it's gives me a table without those repeated rows.
now i want that output in a new table, how do i do?

Comment: Perhaps this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `CREATE TABLE . .  SELECT` :

```
CREATE TABLE table
AS  
   SELECT DISTINCT Country, Zipcode, Plan_Id 
   FROM my_table;
```

By this way you will get data into new table. If you already have a new table then use `INSERT INTO . . . SELECT` instead :

```
INSERT INTO table (Country, Zipcode, Plan_Id) 
   SELECT DISTINCT Country, Zipcode, Plan_Id 
   FROM my_table;
```